# User logged in but it payload gives "undefined" as the result

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working with Dialog Flow and I need to get the userID (to be more specific, Unique ID of the user). The Google Assistant app works fine for logging in but when I'm trying to get Unique ID, I get "undefined" as the result.

I have searched in Google a lot but I could not find the answer.

My Google Assistant app initially lets a user login, then take his Unique ID as the firebase database ID, stores his details in fields (like order details, payment details etc..,) and shows them when the user invokes an Intent related to that.

I have already declared entities and Intents which were specified in the fulfillment.

index.js of Fulfillment -------------------------------

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {
  dialogflow,
  SignIn
} = require("actions-on-google");
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  const app = dialogflow({
    clientId:'<CLIENT ID>'
  });

  app.intent("Sign in user", conv => {
    conv.ask(new SignIn("To personalize"));
  });

  var payload;

  app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
      if (signin.status === 'OK') {
        payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
      }
    }
  );


  function welcome(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv();
    var name = conv.user.access.token;
    agent.add(`Welcome to the Bot ${name}! How can I help?`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  function getOrderDetails(agent) {
    const dbRef = db.collection('users').doc("test");
    return dbRef.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add("Your order status is "+doc.data().orderStatus);
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
      });
  }

  function getPaymentDetails(agent) {
    const dbRef = db.collection('users').doc("test");
    return dbRef.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add("Your payment is "+doc.data().paymentStatus);
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
      });
  }

  function getDeliveryDetails(agent) {
    const dbRef = db.collection('users').doc("test");
    return dbRef.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add("Your delivery Status is "+doc.data().deliveryDetails);
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
      });
  }


  function getAllDetails(agent) {
    const dbRef = db.collection('users').doc("test");
    return dbRef.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add("Delivery details" + doc.data().deliveryDetails + "\nOrder Status " + doc.data().orderStatus + "\nPayment Details " + doc.data().paymentStatus);
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
      });
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('GetDeliveryStatus', getDeliveryDetails);
  intentMap.set('GetPaymentDetails', getPaymentDetails);
  intentMap.set('GetOrderDetails', getOrderDetails);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: What is the configuration you're using for Sign In?

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for your reply. I was expecting your reply by the way :)     I use Actions-on-Google sign In configuration. As provided in "Sign in user" intent in the above code. (Just Google Sign in. Not Google Sign in and OAuth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm having trouble figuring out how your code runs and how you're sending the SignIn request.

You're mixing the actions-on-google library and the dialogflow-fulfillment libraries in an odd way, setting up most of the Intent Handlers to work with the dialogflow-fulfillment library, and the two sign-in related ones to work with the actions-on-google library.

*However*, you're not setting up the a-o-g library to be triggered by webhook (because you setup the d-f library to do that), so those Intents are never called. So it can't be sending the SignIn. So the user doesn't sign-in. So the `user.profile` field is never populated.

Additionally, the `conv.user.access.token` field is only set if you are using the OAuth method to authenticate the user, rather than Google Sign In. You indicated in your comment above that you're not using OAuth, so you should never see this set.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I'll make sure to update the code. Thanks for your time and patience.